# Remote debugging Tools is not working in Windows 8.1 Surface (ARM)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, remote-debugging, windows-rt

I develop Windows 8.1 Store apps using VisualStudio 2013 preview. Hence i have to test my app in the Windows Surface 8.1 (ARM) device to debug. For the remote debugging i installed the VisualStudio 2013 Remote tools for ARM device.

When I try to run the Remote tools exe. I get App cant run in this PC issue in my Windows 8.1 Surface RT. Could you please help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to run the x86/x64 remote debug tools on the ARM tablet because there is no VS2013 remote debugger for ARM.

Comment: There are indeed 2 versions of the remote tools for vs2013. One is [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2013 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39985) and the other one is [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39312).
The RC version was released on Sept 6th, while the Preview one on Aug 21st.
The Preview version has a ARM installer, but the RC do not have any ARM installer. The Preview version doesn't open on my Surface either. Any idea about why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue - this is what i did: I installed the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Tools 2013 (if you have installed already, uninstall it, and also uninstall the one for 2012 too).

After installing it, go to this path in your Surface:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\arm

Inside there should be an executable named **msvsmon.exe**; run it.
When you start the remote debugger for the first time, the dialog is called Remote Debugging Configuration, so just click on "Configure Remote Debugging" button at the bottom.

Pin the msvsmon.exe to the start screen by right-clicking (or using touch, touch and hold until the menu options appear).

This works for me and now im able to deploy into my Surface RT under Windows 8.1, from VS 2013.